# OrderBy without lambda for simple IEnumerables

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a simpler way to write the following? I.E., without the lambda.

```
var strings = new[] { "Alabama", "Mississippi", "Louisiana" };
var ordered = strings.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Seems like it should be possible, since `string` implements `IEquatable<string>`.

Comment: `list.Sort();` maybe?

Comment: Why try to get rid of it??  You just have to be in a positive mindset.  This `(x => x)` is actually an emoji of me walking into a sliding glass door while drunk.

Comment: OrderBy without lambda would not be Order **By** :]

Comment: or `var ordered = new SortedSet(strings);` for distinct values `\(o => o)/`

Answer (score 6):

It's `IComparable` that matters more than`IEquatable` here, but it is possible:

```
Array.Sort(strings);
```

This works because `strings` is already an array. Since you asked for any IEnumerable:

```
var ary = strings.ToArray();
Array.Sort(ary);
```

Note the extra variable is also important in this second sample, because `Array.Sort()` sorts the actual object passed without returning the results, and calling `.ToArray()` created a new array that was then thrown away. Without the extra variable, you lose your work.

There is a similar sort method on the `List<T>` object you can use, as well.

You can also make your own extension method for this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> Sort(this IEnumerable<T> items) where T : IComparable
    {
        return items.OrderBy(i => i);
    }
}
```

And now you could just say:

```
var ordered = strings.Sort();
```

Comment: `Array.Sort(strings.ToArray())` seems silly to me. It creates an array, sorts it in-place, then throws away the result.

Comment: True, but this creates a new array. I was hoping there was a more concise extension method that I was missing that was of the signature `static IEnumerable<T> Order(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable) where T : IComparable<T>;`

Comment: I'll update my answer with a solution that does that.

Comment: Hmm, the question I was attempting to write was looking for a .NET method that does this, without having to add additional extensions. But your method is valid, and answers the question. I think that there is not such an existing .NET method that does what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 7 or higher, use `Order`.

```
var strings = new[] { "Alabama", "Mississippi", "Louisiana" };
var ordered = strings.Order();
```

[dotnet/runtime#67194](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/67194)